# Integral $\int_0^\infty \exp(ia/x^2+ibx^2)dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, improper-integrals, residue-calculus

Compute the integral:

\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty \exp\left(\frac{ia}{x^2}+ibx^2\right)\,dx
\end{equation}

for $a$, $b$ real and positive. I tried complex variables, but don't really know how to handle this.

Comment: The integral does not seem to exist.

Comment: It should exist; book claims it is $ \sqrt{i \pi / 4b}\, e^{2i\sqrt{ab}}$

Comment: Which book? In which sense does it claim convergence since the function to be integrated has modulus $1$ everywhere? As a limit of the integral from $0$ to $R$ when $R\to\infty$?

Comment: Concerning real integrals there is the classical $$\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac a{x^2}-bx^2}dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{4b}}e^{-2\sqrt{ab}}$$ (from the appendix of Feynman&Hibb's "Quantum Mechanics and Path Integrals" ($1965$ edition). By analytic continuation you may probably obtain your result... (with some ambiguity on the sign of the result...)

Comment: I found this integral in the context of a scattering problem in quantum mechanics. The result is in the appendix to "Quantum Mechanics and Path Integrals", by R.Feynman. I don't know in which sense it converges, hoped some mathematician may know

Comment: @Raymond Manzoni, can you sketch how you get explicitly that classical integral?

Comment: @quark1245, I've Feynman's book's appendix in front of me and I think you have a rather boogie-buggy typo: the book's integral has no $\,i\,$ at all in the exponential's argument, making it exactly what Raymond told you! If there was an $\,i\,$ then, as Did told you, the integral's *usual* meaning would diverge...In fact, Feynman's appendix **has** minus in the exponential argument ...

Comment: I have the book open in front of me too and there is an $i$, the integral Raymond says is not there. It's the appendix "Some useful definite integrals", integral A.3, emended edition, Dover edition (2010).

Comment: *I do not have the book open in front of me* but I find this exchange deadly funny.

Comment: @Did The integral from $1$ to $R$ converges as $R$ goes to infinity, and the integral from $\epsilon$ to $1$ converges as $\epsilon$ goes to zero, so this improper integral is well-defined.

Comment: @Zarrax Thanks, I know. :-) By the way, the convergence at $0$ is trivial since the integrand is bounded but the convergence at $+\infty$ requires an argument (either similar to the one you give in your answer, or not).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try to obtain the Laplace integral (from a [proof](http://www.mat.utfsm.cl/scientia/archivos/vol21/vol21art3.pdf) from Albano, Amdeberhan, Beyerstedt and Moll see $5.$) :
$$\tag{1}\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac a{x^2}-bx^2}dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{4b}}e^{-2\sqrt{ab}}$$
Let's suppose $a:=u^2$ and $b:=v^2$ and compute :
$$\tag{2}I=\int_0^\infty e^{-\left(\frac ux-vx\right)^2}dx=e^{2\sqrt{ab}}\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac a{x^2}-bx^2}dx$$
The substitution $\,x:=\dfrac u{v\,z}\,$ gives (after reordering) :
$$I=\frac uv\int_0^\infty e^{-\left(\frac uz-vz\right)^2}\frac{dz}{z^2}$$
adding these equations we get :
$$2\,I=\frac 1v\int_0^\infty e^{-\left(\frac uz-vz\right)^2}\left(\frac u{z^2}+v\right)dz$$
Set $\ \displaystyle t:=\frac uz-v\,z\ $ to get :
$$I=\frac 1{2v}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-t^2}dt=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2v}$$
That we may substitute in $(2)$ to get $(1)$ as wished.
From analytic continuation you may obtain the integral you wanted (this is an argument for physicists! ;-)).

You may see this problem too from the point of view of [Dawson integral](http://dlmf.nist.gov/7.7) of the complementary error function $\operatorname{erfc}$ (see $7.7.7$ and $7.7.8$ for the specific case $x=0$).

Since you are interested by the imaginary case this [paper](http://www.oberlin.edu/physics/dstyer/FeynmanHibbs/Prob6-13.pdf) of Styer may interest you (he considers the error function as previously but with imaginary terms for the problem $6-13$ from the book).

This detailed [errata page](http://www.oberlin.edu/physics/dstyer/FeynmanHibbs/) from Styer for Feynman Hibb's book is related too.

Comment: You can basically do the same thing directly to the original integral; see my answer

Comment: Incredibly good answer, that's exactly the problem I was trying to do

Comment: Thanks @quark1245 (and I thought that $6-13$ could be appropriate...) and thanks Zarrax for the $i$ case.

Comment: I like it too @Mhenni ! A more general formula is $\ \displaystyle \int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{a^2}{x^n}-b^2\,x^n}dx=\frac 2n\left(\frac ab\right)^{\frac 1n}\ \operatorname{K}_{\frac 1n}(2\,ab)$ with $\operatorname{K}_n$ the modified [Bessel function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32) (cf $\,10.32.10$).  
For $n=2$ we got $\ \operatorname{K}_{\frac 12}(z)=\sqrt{\frac {\pi}2}\frac {e^{-z}}{\sqrt{z}}$, for other results ($n=3$ : Airy function and so on) see [Wolfram functions](http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselK/03/01/02/01/).

Answer (score 3):

The integral is the same as 
$$e^{2i \sqrt{ab}}\int_0^{\infty} e^{i ({\sqrt{a} \over x} - \sqrt{b}x)^2}\,dx$$
Letting $x = \sqrt[4]{a \over b}$ $y$, this integral becomes
$$ \sqrt[4]{a \over b} e^{2i \sqrt{ab}}\int_0^{\infty}e^{i\sqrt{ab}(y - {1 \over y})^2}\,dy$$
Changing variables from $y$ to ${1 \over y}$ in the integral gives
$$\int_0^{\infty}e^{i\sqrt{ab}(y - {1 \over y})^2}\,dy = \int_0^{\infty}e^{i\sqrt{ab}(y - {1 \over y})^2}{1 \over y^2}\,dy$$
So the left hand side of the last equation is equal to the average of the left and right hand sides. In other words, 
$$\int_0^{\infty}e^{i\sqrt{ab}(y - {1 \over y})^2}\,dy = {1 \over 2} \int_0^{\infty}e^{i\sqrt{ab}(y - {1 \over y})^2}(1 + {1 \over y^2})\,dy $$
Changing variables here to $z = {y - {1 \over y}}$ gives
$$\int_0^{\infty}e^{i\sqrt{ab}(y - {1 \over y})^2}\,dy = {1 \over 2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i\sqrt{ab}\,z^2}\,dz$$
Letting $z = {1 \over \sqrt[4]{ab}}u$ this is the same as
$${1 \over 2\sqrt[4]{ab}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{iz^2}\,dz$$
This is the famous Fresnel integral, and the above has value ${\displaystyle{e^{i\pi \over 4} \sqrt{\pi} \over 2\sqrt[4]{ab}}}$. Plugging this back in says that the original integral is
$$ e^{i \pi \over 4} {1 \over 2} \sqrt{\pi \over b} e^{2i \sqrt{ab}}$$
This is the answer. There are no convergence issues in the above; since the Fresnel integral converges the argument above is readily made rigorous, and at any rate one can use stationary phase a.k.a. integration by parts to directly show the original improper integral converges in the usual sense.

Comment: +1 and very clear answer, but the other one had extra linked material

Answer (score 0):

We can evaluate the following integral in a closed form, but under the conditions $Re(\alpha) < 0$ and $Re(\beta <0)$

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{\alpha x^2 + \frac{\beta}{x^2}}dx = -{\frac {\,i\sqrt {\pi}{{\rm e}^{2\sqrt{\beta}\sqrt{\alpha}}}}{2\sqrt {\alpha}}}. $$