# Feynman technique of integration for $\int^\infty_0 \exp\left(\frac{-x^2}{y^2}-y^2\right) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I've been learning a technique that Feynman describes in some of his books to integrate. The source can be found here:

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-304-undergraduate-seminar-in-discrete-mathematics-spring-2006/projects/integratnfeynman.pdf

The first few examples are integrals in $x$ and $y$ variables, and I can't see a good way to simplify them using differentiation, particularly the example:

$$\int^\infty_0 \exp\left(\frac{-x^2}{y^2}-y^2\right) dx$$

Comment: Take out $exp(-y^2)$ and integrate directly, it is gaussian.

Comment: I see another example in there that is just $\int_0^\infty \exp(-x^2)dx$.  Would love to see how this technique can be used to provide an alternate derivation.

Comment: is there any way that it is "dy" instead of"dx"?

Comment: If you scroll down to the bottom of the pdf linked it's the first example, unless they made a mistake, it's right.

Comment: Just for note: There is similar, but harder problem, when you have $dy$ instead of $dx$. If you want to solve that problem (where $x$ is parameter, say $x>0$ (but you can do all for $x \in \mathbb{R}$)), first find $I'(x)$ and then use substitution $y \mapsto \frac{x}{t}$ for $I(x)$, where $I(x)$ is your integral. You should end with something like $I'(x)+2I(x)=0$, that is $I(x)=Ce^{-2x}$ (you can find that $C=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$ from $I(0)=\lim_{x \to 0^+} I(x)$).

Comment: Related to Cortizol's comment and Dr. MV's answer see this [thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353841/integral-int-0-infty-expia-x2ibx2dx).

Comment: This page might help https://highvoltagemath.wixsite.com/highvoltagemath/the-gaussian-integral-take-2

Answer (score 5):

Suppose the integral were $I=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-y^2-\frac{x^2}{y^2}}dy$. Then we note that $y^2+\frac{x^2}{y^2}=\left(y-\frac{|x|}{y}\right)^2+2|x|$.

Thus, we have

$$I=e^{-2|x|}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\left(y-\frac{|x|}{y}\right)^2}dy \tag 1$$

Now, substitute $y\to |x|/y$ so that $dy\to -|x|dy/y^2$.  Then,

$$I=e^{-2|x|}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{|x|}{y^2}e^{-\left(y-\frac{|x|}{y}\right)^2}dy \tag 2$$

If we add $(1)$ and (2), we find

$$\begin{align}
I&=\frac12\,e^{-2|x|}\int_0^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{|x|}{y^2}\right)e^{-\left(y-\frac{|x|}{y}\right)^2}dy \\\\
&=\frac12\,e^{-2|x|}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-y^2}dy\\\\
&=e^{-2|x|}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}
\end{align}$$

So, while not quite a "Feynmann" trick, it is an effective way of evaluation.

Answer (score 4):

I looked through the paper and see that the "Feynman Technique" is really just a clever application of Leibniz's rule for taking derivatives under integrals.  As is pointed out in the comments, the interesting part of this is evaluating $$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} dx$$ using the technique.  The paper is a bit misleading for this one since all the other examples added a function of $b$ into the integrand, but that doesn't seem to be the right way to do this one.  Instead consider:
   $$I(b) = \left(\int_0^b e^{-x^2} dx\right)^2$$
Ultimately you want to evaluate that at $b = \infty$ and take its square root.

The full derivation of the result can be found [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/diffunderint.pdf).  That paper discusses this in terms of the Leibniz rule and gives several other interesting derivations of different integrals.